# Convert datetime into a zodiac name

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, datetime

I have a date of someone's birth as "12/02/1980 00:00:00" but I want to convert it into a zodiac name. So I want ***12/02/1980*** to be displayed as ***Sagittarius***. Is that possible to do?

Comment: Yes, but there is obviously no built in method. You do something like CASE WHEN [DateOfBirth] >= '01/01/2000' AND [DateOfBirth] <= '01/04/2000' THEN 'Sagittarius' WHEN [DateOfBirth] >= '01/04/2000' AND [DateOfBirth] <= '01/06/2000' THEN 'OtherOne'... etc.

Comment: Yes, have a table with the start (and end) dates for each of the 12/13 star signs and then join to that.

Comment: Do you REALLY record birthDATES as datetime values? If so, why? Doing so simply increases the odds that your obvious assumption here causes problems at some point in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there's a fixed rule to match birthady and zodiac the easiest way is a CASE:

```
CASE 
    WHEN MONTH(DateOfBirth) * 100 + DAY(DateOfBirth) BETWEEN 0120 AND 0219 THEN 'Aquarius'
    WHEN MONTH(DateOfBirth) * 100 + DAY(DateOfBirth) BETWEEN 0220 AND 0320 THEN 'Pisces'
    WHEN month(DateOfBirth) * 100 + DAY(DateOfBirth) BETWEEN 0321 AND 0419 THEN 'Ares'
    WHEN MONTH(DateOfBirth) * 100 + DAY(DateOfBirth) BETWEEN 0420 AND 0520 THEN 'Taurus'
    WHEN MONTH(DateOfBirth) * 100 + DAY(DateOfBirth) BETWEEN 0521 AND 0620 THEN 'Gemini'
    WHEN MONTH(DateOfBirth) * 100 + DAY(DateOfBirth) BETWEEN 0621 AND 0722 THEN 'Cancer'
    WHEN MONTH(DateOfBirth) * 100 + DAY(DateOfBirth) BETWEEN 0723 AND 0822 THEN 'Leo'
    WHEN MONTH(DateOfBirth) * 100 + DAY(DateOfBirth) BETWEEN 0823 AND 0922 THEN 'Virgo'
    WHEN MONTH(DateOfBirth) * 100 + DAY(DateOfBirth) BETWEEN 0923 AND 1022 THEN 'Libra'
    WHEN MONTH(DateOfBirth) * 100 + DAY(DateOfBirth) BETWEEN 1023 AND 1121 THEN 'Scorpio'
    WHEN MONTH(DateOfBirth) * 100 + DAY(DateOfBirth) BETWEEN 1122 AND 1221 THEN 'Sagittarius'
    ELSE 'Capricorn'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Can do something like this

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE(DateOfBirth DATETIME);
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES ('19800517');

SELECT 
    DateOfBirth,
    CASE 
        WHEN DATEADD(YEAR,-DATEDIFF(YEAR,'19000101',DateOfBirth),DateOfBirth) BETWEEN CAST('19000321' AS DATETIME) AND CAST('19000419' AS DATETIME) THEN 'Ares'
        WHEN DATEADD(YEAR,-DATEDIFF(YEAR,'19000101',DateOfBirth),DateOfBirth) BETWEEN CAST('19000420' AS DATETIME) AND CAST('19000520' AS DATETIME) THEN 'Taurus'
        WHEN DATEADD(YEAR,-DATEDIFF(YEAR,'19000101',DateOfBirth),DateOfBirth) BETWEEN CAST('19000521' AS DATETIME) AND CAST('19000620' AS DATETIME) THEN 'Gemini'
        WHEN DATEADD(YEAR,-DATEDIFF(YEAR,'19000101',DateOfBirth),DateOfBirth) BETWEEN CAST('19000621' AS DATETIME) AND CAST('19000722' AS DATETIME) THEN 'Cancer'
        WHEN DATEADD(YEAR,-DATEDIFF(YEAR,'19000101',DateOfBirth),DateOfBirth) BETWEEN CAST('19000723' AS DATETIME) AND CAST('19000822' AS DATETIME) THEN 'Leo'
        WHEN DATEADD(YEAR,-DATEDIFF(YEAR,'19000101',DateOfBirth),DateOfBirth) BETWEEN CAST('19000823' AS DATETIME) AND CAST('19000922' AS DATETIME) THEN 'Virgo'
        WHEN DATEADD(YEAR,-DATEDIFF(YEAR,'19000101',DateOfBirth),DateOfBirth) BETWEEN CAST('19000923' AS DATETIME) AND CAST('19001022' AS DATETIME) THEN 'Libra'
        WHEN DATEADD(YEAR,-DATEDIFF(YEAR,'19000101',DateOfBirth),DateOfBirth) BETWEEN CAST('19001023' AS DATETIME) AND CAST('19001121' AS DATETIME) THEN 'Scorpio'
        WHEN DATEADD(YEAR,-DATEDIFF(YEAR,'19000101',DateOfBirth),DateOfBirth) BETWEEN CAST('19001122' AS DATETIME) AND CAST('19001221' AS DATETIME) THEN 'Sagittarius'
        WHEN DATEADD(YEAR,-DATEDIFF(YEAR,'19010101',DateOfBirth),DateOfBirth) BETWEEN CAST('19001222' AS DATETIME) AND CAST('19010119' AS DATETIME) THEN 'Capricorn'
        WHEN DATEADD(YEAR,-DATEDIFF(YEAR,'19000101',DateOfBirth),DateOfBirth) BETWEEN CAST('19000120' AS DATETIME) AND CAST('19000219' AS DATETIME) THEN 'Aquarius'
        WHEN DATEADD(YEAR,-DATEDIFF(YEAR,'19000101',DateOfBirth),DateOfBirth) BETWEEN CAST('19000220' AS DATETIME) AND CAST('19000320' AS DATETIME) THEN 'Pisces'
    END
FROM @temp
```

Comment: This fails for end-of-year Capricorns, e.g. '1980-12-24'

Comment: Capricorn (astrology)
Capricorn
Zodiac symbol Sea goat
Duration (tropical, western) December 21 – January 19 (2020, UT1)
Constellation Capricornus
Zodiac element Earth

, Capricornians are till 1980-12-19

Comment: End-of-year dates return NULL, see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0d5070488ba93b457bfd77bb04d28654

Answer (score 0):

One way to convert any datetime (or datetime2) would be to use a table valued function.  The following tvf doesn't reference any physical tables so (for slight performance advantage) it can be specified 'WITH SCHEMABINDING' which means the function doesn't have to check for the existence of objects prior to binding.  The sign Capricorn spans end-of-year and beginning-of-year month/date ranges so it's entered on 2 rows in the zodiac_table virtual table.

tvf

```
drop function if exists [dbo].convert_datetime_to_zodiac;
go
create function [dbo].convert_datetime_to_zodiac(
    @dtm       datetime2)
returns table with schemabinding as return 
with z_cte(start_mo, start_day, end_mo, end_day, zodiac_sign) as (
    select start_mo, start_day, end_mo, end_day, zodiac_sign 
    from (values (3, 21, 4, 19, 'Ares'),
                 (4, 20, 5, 19, 'Taurus'),
                 (5, 21, 6, 19, 'Gemini'),
                 (6, 21, 7, 19, 'Cancer'),
                 (7, 23, 8, 19, 'Leo'),
                 (8, 23, 9, 19, 'Virgo'),
                 (9, 23, 10, 19, 'Libra'),
                 (10, 23, 11, 19, 'Scorpio'),
                 (11, 22, 12, 19, 'Sagittarius'),
                 (12, 22, 12, 31, 'Capricorn'),
                 (1, 1, 1, 19, 'Capricorn'),
                 (1, 20, 2, 19, 'Aquarius'),
                 (2, 20, 3, 20, 'Pisces'))
                 zodiac_table(start_mo, start_day, 
                              end_mo, end_day, zodiac_sign))
select z.zodiac_sign
from z_cte z
     cross apply (select year(@dtm) dtm_yr) dtm
where cast(@dtm as date) between datefromparts(dtm.dtm_yr, z.start_mo, z.start_day)
                             and datefromparts(dtm.dtm_yr, z.end_mo, z.end_day);
go
```

Query examples

```
select * from dbo.convert_datetime_to_zodiac('05/02/1980 00:00:00');
select * from dbo.convert_datetime_to_zodiac('01/22/1980 00:00:00');
select * from dbo.convert_datetime_to_zodiac('01/02/1980 00:00:00');
```

Outputs

```
zodiac_sign
Taurus

zodiac_sign
Aquarius

zodiac_sign
Capricorn
```

If the datetime is in a table then CROSS APPLY using the tvf like this

```
with table_containing_a_date_cte as (
    select cast('03/27/1999 00:00:00' as datetime) as dtm)
select conv.zodiac_sign
from table_containing_a_date_cte dc
     cross apply dbo.convert_datetime_to_zodiac(dc.dtm) conv;
```

Outputs

```
zodiac_sign
Ares
```